# which spring version to choose to start a project from scratch?

Tags: spring

I am starting a new project from scratch. I want to know which spring version  to choose.Is spring 5.0 (functional web framework) is mature enough to start with or do I need to rely on lower spring versions? Please help.

Comment: This question is too broad. Do you have any technical requirement (spring related) that could make less broad this question and help us?

Comment: Its a very simple question... To start spring web application from scratch at this time,Shall I start it in spring 5.0 is it mature enough ? or Shall I do it in 4 itself? I just want to know whether spring 5.0 is stable enough and I will get all necesary helps..

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am working on a Spring Boot Project where I am using Spring 4.3.5. 
version It is working perfectly it contains all the properties.